# Fastest algorithm for non-empty bins

Tags: reference-request

Assume we have $n$ bins, and exactly $k>0$ of them, are non-empty. Furthermore, assume that we can check if
a specific urn is empty in constant time. I am looking for a randomized algorithm that outputs a number $ ≥ 0$, such that
$E[] = 1/k$.

I am looking for fastest algorithm which can solve the above problem in expectation.
Please refer me to the paper or material which covers it.

One idea is randomly pick a bin and repeat it until non empty is found. Let us say $r$ rounds requires then return $r/n$. The runtime will be $O(n/k)$. I looking for the faster known for this problem.

Comment: Hmm. The algorithm I can think of is to independently draw two random nonempty bins by rejection sampling, and output 1 or 0 according to whether they are the same bin. This takes $2n/k$ samples in expectation.

Comment: Oh, better: draw *one* nonempty bin by rejection sampling (that is, keep sampling bins until you find a nonempty one), and output $s/n$, where $s$ is the number of samples you took.

Comment: @
Emil Jeřábek Thanks. Is this the fastest known?

Comment: It’s the fastest known to *me* after giving it 5 minutes of thought. I have no idea if a better one is known to humanity.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, yes, yes, I think a faster one is known.  This would make an excellent homework question!  Here's a hint (in [ROT13](https://puretables.com/rot13-to-text)):
Tvira na rcfvyba > 0, V pna qb vg va rcfvyba rkcrpgrq dhrevrf.

Comment: @user154062, can you please edit the post to explain the context in which your problem arises?  Also, what you have found so far?

Comment: @NealYoung LOL. However: jung vs lbh erfgevpg L gb or orgjrra mreb naq bar?

Comment: @mathworker21, in that case, by an adversary argument, $\Omega(n)$ queries are required, essentially because the alg must distinguish $k=1$ (when $X$ has to be one all the time) from $k=2$ (when $X$ can be 1 at most half the time).

Comment: @ 
Neal Young Above problem is related to the paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.07567.pdf

Comment: Is that paper about estimates that hold with high probability?  That would have a different answer than "in expectation" (from the post).

Comment: @
Neal Young Yes true. I am looking for an answer in expectation.